# Jmeter with selenium webdriver plugin-start firefox session without cleaning cookies/cache

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter 2.13 alongside with a selenium webdriver plugin. When I start my thread it opens a new firefox session with all the cookies and cache cleared. In a previous session I have made a sync that lasts almost 5 minutes that brings me in my app some products. I don`t want to sync everytime I start the thread.

Is there any way I could start the new firefox session without clearing cookies/cache ?

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, that Selenium is the one that is opening an instance of Firefox, please see below. If not, please provide more info about what you have setup with code examples.

By default Selenium is opening the Firefox in Safe mode, where a lot of stuff are disabled (like extensions, localstore settings, etc). This also means that you won't have any cache or cookies.

You can read more about this [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode).

To disable this, you need to set the `toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes` setting key in in `about:config` to `-1`.

Selenium code wise, this can be achieved by setting the preference in the `FirefoxProfile`. C# code to achieve it would look like this:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("toolkit.startup.max_resumed_crashes", "-1");

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [FirefoxDriverConfig.java](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/webdriver/src/com/googlecode/jmeter/plugins/webdriver/config/FirefoxDriverConfig.java) source code the plugin creates new profile each time Firefox starts:

```
FirefoxProfile createProfile() {
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    String userAgentOverride = getUserAgentOverride();
    String ntlmOverride = getNtlmSetting();
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userAgentOverride)) {
        profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", userAgentOverride);
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(ntlmOverride)) {
        profile.setPreference("network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1", true);
    }

    profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);

    addExtensions(profile);
    setPreferences(profile);

    return profile;
}
```

So there are 2 options:

1. Get plugin source code and amend profile initialisation line to use your existing profile as:

   ```
   FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile("/path/to/firefox/profile");
   ```

   See [How do I find my profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile) page of Mozilla documentation for instructions on how you can locate your current profile directory.
2. Stop using WebDriver Sampler and switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) instead, it supports all the languages WebDriver Sampler does and provides full control (you'll have to write all the code to configure, start and stop browser yourself)